# What is the difference between Template 10 templates?

Tags: template10

I have created new projects using the Template 10 Blank, Minimal and Hamburger templates.

I can see the Hamburger template adds the Models and Services folders. The Minimal template also adds a Converters folder.

Beyond creating these folders, how do the project templates differ? I have read the [Template 10 Documentation](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki) and [Template10: a new template to create Universal Windows apps](http://blog.qmatteoq.com/template10-a-new-template-to-create-universal-windows-apps-the-controls/). The Channel9 video [Template 10: How to Build Your Universal Windows App...minus all of the repetitive, tedious, boilerplate](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/DevRadio/DR1622) discusses Basic and Minimal. In this video Minimal includes the hamburger menu.

Can anyone point me to a succinct summary of the differences between the three Template 10 templates?

Answer (score 0):

This has now been answered in the Microsoft Virtual Academy course:

[Getting Started with Template 10](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/getting-started-with-template-10-16336?l=kuIxVfXRC_8505918567)

As I understand it, the Minimal template implements navigation. The Hamburger template creates a shell which becomes the root frame.